# Change schema name for different environment in JPA annotation in Telosys generated code

Tags: java, schema, database-schema, auto-generate, telosys

I am generating my classes using spring jpa template in Telosys generator tool. It works as expected, however, my project has different database schemas for different environment which I can't handle. So my entity classes need to have respective schema name which will mean me connecting each database schema and generating environment specific classes.
I am trying to pass the schema name from gradle variable and use that in entity class

```
schema = "${property.schema.name}"
```

But since these are generated classes by Telosys, all JPA annotations are handled by the template.
Is there a way to set the schema name in the annotation like above? or any alternate solution to the problem of different schemas is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If your database schema is the same for all entities you can just define a specific **project global variable** in the file "**telosys-tools.cfg**".
See : https://doc.telosys.org/configuration-and-variables
In your case:  `ProjectVariable.DBSCHEMA  = yourschema`
You can use it directly in the templates with `${DBSCHEMA}`:

If you have specific schema only for certain entities you can use the `@DbSchema(your-schema-name)` annotation (at entity level) in the ".entity" files
See : https://doc.telosys.org/dsl-model/annotations#dbschema-string
Annotations like `@DbSchema` and `@DbCatalog` are automatically used by `$jpa` object in the templates.

Comment: Thank you @Igu. I really appreciate it. My schema name is changing for all entities as environment changes. And because I do not want to re generate all the entity classes and commit the code for just schema name change I am trying to find a way that Iit could be configured explicitly while I either deploy it or build it using gradle or properties. What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your need. But if you don't want to re-generate, then the solution cannot be provided by the generator.
You can try to dive inside JPA/Hibernate. 
Perhaps with hibernate.default_schema  in configuration ?

Comment: Yes @Igu, I am looking into default schema config. One solution I could find was to have schema placeholder in entity class annotation and pass the variabl from gradle. But since it is generated by Telosys, can you please suggest what should I do to put like in my question instead of actual schema name

Comment: The docs url is not working @Igu.

Comment: it was just a temporary problem with the host, it works normally now.

Comment: DbSchema annotation needs an import @Igu. Can you help with an example. what change should I do in my template .entity